# Quantum Harmonic osciallator in $E$-field (old and new eigenstates)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-fields, harmonic-oscillator

Consider a quantum harmonic oscillator with Hamiltonian defined as
$$ H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2 - qEx.$$
Also, consider a normal harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian to be $H_0=\frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$.

Let the eigenstates of $H$ be $|n, E\rangle$ and eigenstates of $H_0$ be $|n\rangle$. At $t = 0$, we found the particle to be in $|0\rangle$. What is the probability of finding
the particle to be in $|0\rangle$ at time $t$? For what time $t$ is the probability maximum?

It immediately came to my mind to try time evolution. After time $t$, we should find the particle to be in a state (it is relatively straight forward to find the eigen-energy for $|n,E\rangle$, so I'll skip that)
$$|\varphi(t)\rangle = \sum_n \exp\left\{-i\left[\omega\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)t - \frac{q^2E^2}{2m\omega^2\hbar}\right]\right\}|n, E\rangle\langle n, E|0\rangle \\
\langle 0|\varphi(t)\rangle = \sum_n \exp\left\{-i\left[\omega\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)t - \frac{q^2E^2}{2m\omega^2\hbar}\right]\right\}|\langle n, E|0\rangle|^2.$$

OK, now I got stuck, this is going to give a quite complicated expression for the probability.

Edit: The original question is clearly not too clear if anything happened at $t = 0$. Let's say if the electric field has always been there, it is not suddenly terned on. Is it sensible to say we find the state to be $|0\rangle$ at $t = 0$? Or it is not possible since we have to find the state to be an eigenstate of $H$ since electric field is always there?

Comment: This question is unclear. Does the Hamiltonian change at $t=0$ from $H_0$ to $H$ because an electric field is turned on?

Comment: Why not computing $\langle0|e^{-i\hat{H}t/\hbar}|0\rangle$ directly instead of introducing some unknown eigenstates (with unknown eigenvalues moreover) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Express the position operator $X$ and the momentum operator $P$ in terms of the ladder operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$ satisfying the commutation relation $[a,a^\dagger]=1$ via  $$X=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}(a+a^\dagger), \quad  P=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar m \omega}{2}}i(a^\dagger-a)$$ leading to $$H_0=\hbar \omega(a^\dagger a +1/2), \quad H=\hbar \omega \left[a^\dagger a +1/2-z(a+a^\dagger)\right]$$ with $z=qE/ \sqrt{2m \hbar \omega^3}$. The ground state vector $|0\rangle$ of $H_0$ is characterized by $a|0\rangle=0$ and the normalization condition $\langle 0|0\rangle=1$.
2. Introduce the operators $b=a-z$ and $b^\dagger=a^\dagger-z$ satisfying the commutation relation $[b,b^\dagger]=1$ and rewrite the Hamilton operator $H$ in the form $$H=\hbar \omega (b^\dagger b +1/2-z^2).$$ The ground state vector $|0,E\rangle$ of the Hamilton operator $H$ is determined by $b|0,E\rangle=0$ and the normalization condition $\langle 0,E |0,E\rangle=1$. The eigenvectors $|n,E\rangle$ of $H$ are obtained by successively applying the ladder operator $b^\dagger$ on the ground state,$$|n,E\rangle = \frac{(b^\dagger)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|0,E\rangle, \quad H|n,E\rangle = \hbar \omega (n+1/2-z^2) |n, E\rangle.  $$
3. Expand the vector $|0\rangle$ with respect to the basis $\left\{ |n,E\rangle\right\}_{n=0}^\infty$. To this end, start with the ansatz $|0\rangle = f(b^\dagger)|0,E\rangle$ with a still to be determined function $f$. As $a|0\rangle=(b+z) |0\rangle=0$, we obtain $$(b+z)f(b^\dagger)|0,E\rangle=[b,f(b^\dagger)]|0,E\rangle+z f(b^\dagger)|0,E\rangle=0.$$ The commutation relation $[b,b^\dagger]=1$ implies $[b,f(b^\dagger)]=f^\prime(b^\dagger)$, leading to the the equation $$\left[f^\prime(b^\dagger)+zf(b^\dagger)\right]|0,E\rangle=0.$$ This relation is fulfilled if the function $f$ satisfies the differential equation $f^\prime(x)=-zf(x)$, i.e. $f(x)=C e^{-zx}$. The desired expression for the vector $|0\rangle$ is thus given by $|0\rangle = C e^{-zb^\dagger} |0,E\rangle$. As $$ e^{-zb^\dagger}|0,E\rangle= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-zb^\dagger)^n}{n!} |0,E\rangle=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-z)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|n,E\rangle, $$ the normalization condition $\langle 0|0\rangle=1$ implies $|C|=e^{-z^2/2}$ for the normalization constant $C$. The expansion of the vector $|0\rangle$ with repect to the basis of the eigenvectors of $H$ is thus given by $$|0\rangle =e^{-z^2/2} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-z)^n}{\sqrt{n!}} |n,E\rangle.$$
4. In the Schrödinger picture, the time evolution of a state the governed by the Hamiltonian $H$ is given by $|\phi(t)\rangle = e^{-iHt/\hbar}| \phi(0)\rangle$. Assuming that the system is initially prepared in the state $|\phi(0)\rangle=|0\rangle$, the corresponding time evolution is given by $$|\phi(t)\rangle = e^{-iHt/\hbar} |0\rangle=e^{-z^2/2}e^{-i\omega t(1/2-z^2)} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-z e^{-i\omega t})^n}{\sqrt{n!}} |n,E\rangle   $$  and $$\langle 0 |\phi(t)\rangle =e^{-i\omega t(1/2-z^2)} e^{-z^2} e^{z^2 \cos \omega t} e^{-i z^2 \sin \omega t},$$ yielding the probability $$|\langle 0|\phi(t)\rangle|^2= e^{-2z^2 (1-\cos \omega t)}.$$